# Как реализовать блокировки в MSSQL, используя c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Добрый день. Имеется приложение, на C#, работающее с базой данных. У меня, как у новичка, возник вопрос, как реализовать блокировки в приложени, чтобы избежать ситуаций, когда один пользователь открывает запись, чтобы отредактировать в то время, когда она открыта у другого пользователя.

Я пробовал заворачивать в одну транзакцию загрузку данных в форму и сохранение, то есть транзакция будет жить столько, сколько открыта форма редактирования. Однако, когда я попытался одновременно открыть вторую копию программы и ту же запись в ней, то SQL выдал таймаут операции. 
Хотелось бы, чтобы он выдавал сообщение, что запись уже открыта.
Это реально сделать? Правильно ли я вообще поступаю?

Comment: При открытии документа проверяете установлен ли где-то в базе флаг "документ заблокирован". Если да, выдаете сообщение, иначе открываете документ, и устанавливаете этот флаг. При закрытии сбрасываете. Не забудьте предусмотреть случаи типа "пользователь открыл документ, забыл закрыть и уехал в отпуск на полгода".

Answer (score 3):

Вариант пессимистичного конкурентного доступа к данным - не самый лучший, на мой взгляд лучше применить оптимистичный доступ как описано тут: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa0416cz(v=vs.110).aspx

Или как это реализовано в Entity Framework https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904.aspx

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, блокировки в SQL работают через ожидание - т.е. код, пытающийся поставить блокировку на уже заблокированную запись, просто ждет пока первая блокировка пройдет.

Кроме того, блокировка на долгих транзакциях ненадежна, т.к. обрыв соединения с приложением, которое держит блокировку, приведет к откату транзакции и снятию блокировки.

Вам стоит ввести явное поле вида "Кем Заблокировано", и обновлять его примерно так:

```sql
UPDATE SomeTable SET LockedBy = @currentUserID
WHERE SomeTableID = @idToLock AND LockedBy IS NULL
```

и проверять количество обновленных строк. Если оно равно 1 - то блокировка успешно установлена для текущего пользователя. Если не 1 - то запись уже заблокирована кем-то.

Снимать блокировку установкой `LockedBy` в `NULL`.

Также стоит предусмотреть отслеживание времени установки блокировки и снятие ее по таймауту.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите здесь, подробно описаны все блокировки 
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=A9pvcnV7hvo